# MinGW compiles successfully, but while running the program, I get an error "this version of 'program' is not compatible'?

Tags: c, mingw, dev-c++

I recently started learning C.
I started by installing Dev-C++. It is working perfectly fine; compiles the source-code file and runs it with no issues.

However, when I compile and run the program (both in cmd in Windows), I get an error. When I compile in Dev-C++ and run in Command prompt, then no issues.

Here's what I am doing- Create a source file (simple 'hello world') and then compile it in cmd.

`gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld`

And it compiles just fine.

But then I run it and this error pops up

```
This version of C:\users\hp\my documents\prog\c\learn\hellworld.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need a 32-bit or 64-bit version of the program.
```

When I use Dev-C++ to compile and run the same source file, there are no issues. and I think Dev-c++ also uses minGW as a compiler. So not sure why it messes up using command prompt.

- I am using 32 bit windows 7
- Dev-C++ is latest (although, it seems the latest is 2015 version)

One more information, which I am not sure is relevant or not, is that I didn't install MinGW separately. I simply installed Dev-C++. I did, however, added the path of 'bin' folder that's inside MinGW in my System Variables.

Please help. I could code through Dev-C++ directly, but I want to know why I can't do it through command prompt.

Sorry, if the questions are too silly. I have just started learning.

Thanks in advance,
Vivid

Comment: The conflict could be in the path you added.  Is there a default `bin` directory that was installed with your environment (i.e. installation of MinGW?

Comment: @ryyker There is a 'bin' directory inside the installed folder for dev-c++. Its path is `C:\Dev-C++\MinGW64\bin`. I added this same path.
EDIT: it says MingGW64, and my computer is 32 bit. could that be an issue?

Comment: If your OS is 32 bit, I am surprised an installer would put something in a ..\MinGW64\.. directory.  And yes, that  could be a problem.

Comment: Exactly. I am surprised, too. But there is no separate installment for 32-bit. There is just one single setup for Dev-C++. It's supposed to work on both 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: sorry to hear of this issue - I teach students C and encourage them to install IDE/compiler to work at home.... the students find that Pelles C is really simple to install and use (http://www.smorgasbordet.com/pellesc/) so I wonder if you might want to try that instead -- sorry this is not the answer you want, but it could be much easier to install something else rather than fight to try and solve this issue because as I see it your main goal is to be able to program in C

Comment: @tom Thanks for your suggestion. I appreciate that. Well, in my case, the interesting thing is that I am being able to code perfectly using dev-c++ as IDE. So if I just wanted to code, I could use it. however, I just NEED to know why it doesn't work with command prompt. :)